# What‘s the difference between the two sentences with by and without by?

Tags: grammar, adverbial-phrases

I know that both prepositional phrase and present participle can be adverbial modifier, but how should I decided which one is should be used when they were used to show a particular method or way of doing something.  As in the following two sentence.

**Sentence 1:**

> Those are some of the reasons why the father told his son, "Always
>   give your wife what she wants." And why he also issued these words of
>   caution, "Always treat her as you would treat a queen." That's because
>   relationships can swing both ways with equal force. You can avoid a
>   lot of problems **by giving in to her**, and you can also cause a lot of
>   problems ***by giving in to her***.

**Sentence 2:**

> You can make a lot more money ***using the bank's money***, and you can lose
>   a lot more money ***using the bank's money.*** So the price to pay is an
>   investment in your education and several years of experience.

***My Questions:***

**1, Can I put the word by in the second sentence right before using?**

**2, How to decided which form is the most proper one to choose when using them as adverbial modifier, gerund or present participle?**

**3，Can I remove the word by from the first sentence?**

**4, Is the present participle phrase in the second sentence indicates in which way and method, or time?**

*In general, I don't think I can remove the propitiation by in sentence 1, but just don't know how to explain it.*

Comment: In question 1 do you actually mean **second** sentence? There is no **using** in the first.

Comment: oops~yes it means second sentence

Comment: So we are interested about whether we could insert **by** before using in the second sentence, or remove **by** from the first one. I find it hard to see a reason, but for sure **avoid problems by giving in** seems to need that **by** and although it does make sense to say **make money by using the bank's money** the **by** here does not seem so important.

Comment: This is what I want to know that when can we drop the word by to turn the prepositional phrase (by doing something) into present participle(doing something) and to express in which(what) way that something to be done or achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself, Could I substitute  the word **when** here for the word **by**, or introduce the word **when**, without changing the meaning?

If you can substitute or introduce the word **when** without changing the meaning, then you can use the bare participle without the preposition.

> You can get a lot of cuts and bruises (when) playing rugby.
>   You can get a lot of cuts and bruises playing rugby.
>
> You can avoid a lot of problems by giving in to her.
>   You can avoid a lot of problems **when** giving in to her. [different meaning]
>   You can avoid a lot of problems giving in to her.  [meaning is unclear]

To use the word **by** there with the rugby example is not impossible (by playing rugby), but it is slightly comical, because the object of the preposition **by** is *the instrumentality through which we achieve or obtain something*.

Were you *attempting* to get cuts and bruises? No. Were you attempting to avoid a lot of problems with the wife? Yes. Thus, "**by** giving in to her".

Comment: As you said, 'you can also cause a lot of problems by giving in to her.' For this sentence in which we use word by is because there is a word also. Is that right? If it went like this:" you can cause a lot of problems by giving in to her." It will like what you said that it is slightly comical.

Comment: Achieving ends and causing things are quite different.  The difference between **by** and **when** is not so marked, with causality.  You can cause problems when giving in to her. You can cause problems by giving in to her.

Comment: What about for this two sentences: 1) He makes a living driving truck. 2) He makes a living by driving truck. Both driving truck and by driving truck here are adverbial modifier indicates means and methods. So, as in this kind of situation, when do we use the word by and when do we left it out?

Comment: Substituting or introducing **when** is a valid test to decide whether you can use the bare participle with a preposition, but it is not the *only* condition under which a preposition can be dropped.  We do say *He makes his living selling cars*.  *He got sick eating spoiled food.*

Comment: Can I remove the word by in first sentence? Also, in the second sentence, is 'using bank's money' to indicate time or in what way and methods?

Comment: *When using the bank's money* is a condition that obtains over time.

Comment: You can drop **by** with "You can avoid a lot of problems giving in to her" but the meaning is potentially unclear.  Are you asking these questions having as your goal the ability to express yourself clearly and unambiguously in English, or are you interested in the grammar for its own sake?  How a question has been tagged is not always a clear indicator of the questioner's goals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44473/discussion-between-henry-wang-and-tromano).